# Why are these matrices coset representatives for $\Gamma_0(2)$ in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-forms

Consider the group $$\Gamma_0(2)=\left\lbrace \begin{pmatrix} 
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix}\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})\mid c\equiv 0 \pmod2\right\rbrace$$
and 
$ I=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} $ ,
 $S=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} $ , $T^{-1}S=\begin{pmatrix} 
-1 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ , with $T=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$

Now I want to show that these matrices are coset representatives of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) /\Gamma_0(2)$

I know that there are three cosets since $|SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) /\Gamma_0(2)|=3$

$SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) /\Gamma_0(2)=\lbrace I,S,T^{-1}S \rbrace$

I think $"\supset"$ is clear because these matrices are in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $I \in \Gamma_0(2)$ .

For the other inclusion, I have no idea.

Thanks for the help.